# How to refresh unity launcher icons from python

Tags: python, unity

I have written a program that runs from the unity launcher.  In my preferences it would be useful for users to change the default icon of the .desktop launcher.  I've set it up to change the file, but changes don't take effect until the user logs out and back in (or unity --replace).

Is there a simple way to trigger Unity to refresh its icons using python?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this (also, I prefer setsid unity over unity replace).

Comment: So far the only way I've found to do it is to remove the launcher from the launcher favorite list and then re-add it.  Unfortunately, removing the item also closes the program if it's open.

Comment: Since this is a programming question, perhaps ask over at StackOverflow?